# Building libtorrent, cannot find boost headers

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, header-files, libtorrent

I'm trying to build libtorrent [library found here](http://www.libtorrent.org/building.html).

I've followed the instructions found in this tutorial, and yet after executing bjam command I'm getting error saying that

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\src\parse_url.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\src\ConvertUTF.o
In file included from include/libtorrent/ConvertUTF.h:91:0,
                 from src\ConvertUTF.cpp:42:
include/libtorrent/config.hpp:45:28: fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

/*EDIT*/
I went even further, I've replaced each include directory from relative to absolute and !!!still!!! I am getting identical error:

```
...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\src\policy.o...
gcc.compile.c++ bin\gcc-mingw-5.1.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi\src\puff.o
In file included from src\puff.cpp:74:0:
C:/libtorrent/boost_1_59_0/boost/cstdint.hpp:36:28: fatal error: boost/config.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

**HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE!?!?!**

Comment: normally boost build will also print the full command line it executed that failed. It will probably confirm or deny whether that the correct include path was added for boost.

Comment: @Arvid, Hi, as I've already explained in my email correspondence with you, boost root is set correctly, which you saw for yourself in the screenshot I've attached in one of my emails to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for that library to actually find boost path bjam needs to be invoked with boost=source parameter. Arvid somehow doesn't make it explicit/clear.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like path to directory with headers is missing.
Did you set BOOST_ROOT?

> When building libtorrent, the Jamfile expects the environment variable BOOST_ROOT to be set to the boost installation directory.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Jost Thank you for explanation.
Do I need to delete my answer?

Comment: @Jost hmm, I don't think it was the right call, in that case. Don't delete your answer, it does point out what could be the reason to that error.